# PHP : Calling parent's overridden method

Tags: php

Given the following example:

```
class Base {
    function method() {
        echo "Base";
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    function method() {
        echo "Child";
    }
}

$obj = new Child();
$obj->method();   // Expected ans is `Base`
```

Can we call the method `a()` from parent class, using the object of child class?

Is there any way other than creating a new method, that would use `parent` keyword?

I looked into `traits`, and seemed to be achievable that way, by using `insteadof`.

But wondering if we can do this by any other OOP concept.

Comment: You shouldn't want to do this in the first place. It's an internal implementation detail of `Child` that there exists a parent method at all. No code other than `Child` should call the parent method, unless your goal is to write horribly tangled code.

Answer (score 1):

Not like that, no. You have overridden the method.

*Inside* the method, you may do `parent::method()` to call the parent method, however usually you would only ever see this in `__construct` or `__destruct`, and even then only rarely.

Comment: Why "only ever see this in __construct or __destruct, and even then only rarely" ?